# Cycle Jquery UI Tab on "previous" and "next" button

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, cycle

I am using Jquery UI Tabs for my website.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#myTabs').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' }});

jQuery('.next-product').click(function(){ 
var jQuerytabs = jQuery('#myTabs').tabs();
var selected = jQuerytabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
jQuerytabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
});

jQuery('.previous-product').click(function(){ 
var jQuerytabs = jQuery('#myTabs').tabs();
var selected = jQuerytabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
jQuerytabs.tabs('select', selected-1);
});
```

As you can see that i have been using the previous next button to move from one tab to another.
My question is "**When i click on next and if the last tab is open then automatically the first tab should get open, and similarly When i click on previous and if the first tab is open then automatically the last tab should get open**"

*Please help me out, i am stuck from over 3 days now and no solution. I have searched a lot on net but no solution for this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of `.ui-tabs-panel` elements.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    var $tabs = jQuery('#myTabs');

    $tabs.tabs({
        fx: {
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }
    });

    var amount = $tabs.find('.ui-tabs-panel').length;

    jQuery('.next-product').click(function() {
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $tabs.tabs('select', selected + 1 === amount ? 0 : selected + 1);
    });

    jQuery('.previous-product').click(function() {
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $tabs.tabs('select', selected === 0 ? amount - 1 : selected - 1);
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/W7AE8/)**

Notes:

- select your tab element already and re-use the selector `var $tabs = jQuery('#myTabs');`, it'll be more efficient
- no need to re-call `.tabs()` on your click handlers

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply man, you really sorted out my problem... This works great. You are truly awesome.

Comment: Hello Didier,
Thanks for the help, I am again stuck at one place.
I need to change the fx effect of the tabs so that i can slide it the way image sliders use to slide.
Link from right to left - one moving behind other.
Or you can check out this example :- http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html 
Here content move taking the next content along with it. If you can help.
Thanks :)

Comment: It's best you post a new question for this. In the meantime, I don't know if you have to use the jQuery Tabs plugin to achieve this, check this [tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/).